# How do I get the absolute path from the settings file in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a simple question:

I have read a lot of answers in this forum on how to get a project's root directory. However I'm running into a problem: the path is just .

For example:

```
from django.conf import settings

path = settings.BASE_DIR + /somefolder/
```

the resulting value for path is just .

I need the full path in order to save to that folder.

Comment: What's the output of just `settings.BASE_DIR`?

Comment: If I use "python manage.py shell", I get the full absolute path. But if I print it from the code in the view, I get a . (just a point).

Comment: Make sure that you're not using root privilège when you create your project.

Comment: It's a windows machine and the project was created with an admin account. Could that be it?

Comment: You're not connected as the same account that created the project?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an admin account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

folder_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'somefolder')
```